# EntityManager in OIM

Tags: java, oracle11g, identity-management, oim

I am using EntityManager API in OIM to update attribute. Below is the code. But I am getting exception at "entMgr.modifyEntity("User",userLogin, mapAttrs);". Is this because of using userlogin? and I am getting userlogin from adapter in run time and it is string. Can someone please help me on this ?

code:

```
  HashMap<String, Object> mapAttrs = new HashMap<String, Object>();         
                        mapAttrs.put("Street", response);  

                        EntityManager entMgr = Platform.getService(EntityManager.class); 
                        logger.info("EntityManager is intialized"+ entMgr);
                        logger.info("User Login::"+userLogin);
                        try {
                            logger.info("Entered into try");
                            entMgr.modifyEntity("User",userLogin, mapAttrs);
                            logger.info("Attribute Updation is succesfull");
                            response="SUCCESS";
                            logger.info("Response::"+ response);
                            return response;
                        } catch (InvalidDataTypeException e) {
                            logger.info("InvalidDataTypeException  has been encountered");

                            e.printStackTrace();
                            response="FAILURE";
                            return response;
                        } catch (InvalidDataFormatException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            logger.info("InvalidDataFormatException  has been encountered");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            response="FAILURE";
                            return response;
                        } catch (NoSuchEntityException e) {
                            logger.info("NoSuchEntityException  has been encountered");
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            response="FAILURE";
                            return response;
                        } catch (StaleEntityException e) {
                            logger.info("StaleEntityException  has been encountered");
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            response="FAILURE";
                            return response;
                        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                            logger.info("UnsupportedOperationException  has been encountered");
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            response="FAILURE";
                            return response;
                        } catch (UnknownAttributeException e) {
                            logger.info("UnknownAttributeException  has been encountered");
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            response="FAILURE";
                            return response;
                        } catch (ProviderException e) {
                            logger.info("ProviderException  has been encountered");
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            response="FAILURE";
                            return response;
                        }  

                    }
```

Exception :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "BYUNJ"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
        at oracle.iam.oimdataproviders.impl.OIMUserDataProvider.modify(OIMUserDataProvider.java:614)
        at oracle.iam.platform.entitymgr.impl.EntityManagerImpl.modifyEntity(EntityManagerImpl.java:607)
        at oracle.iam.platform.entitymgr.impl.EntityManagerImpl.modifyEntity(EntityManagerImpl.java:564)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at oracle.iam.platform.utils.DMSMethodInterceptor.invoke(DMSMethodInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy362.modifyEntity(Unknown Source)
com.thortech.xl.dataobj.util.tcAdapterTaskException: For input string: "BYUNJ"
        at com.thortech.xl.adapterGlue.ScheduleItemEvents.adpHRBPGROUPASSIGN.ASSIGNHRBPGROUP(adpHRBPGROUPASSIGN.java:121)
        at com.thortech.xl.adapterGlue.ScheduleItemEvents.adpHRBPGROUPASSIGN.implementation(adpHRBPGROUPASSIGN.java:60)
        at com.thortech.xl.client.events.tcBaseEvent.run(tcBaseEvent.java:221)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.runEvent(tcDataObj.java:2496)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcScheduleItem.runMilestoneEvent(tcScheduleItem.java:3437)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcScheduleItem.eventPostInsert(tcScheduleItem.java:811)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.insert(tcDataObj.java:606)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcDataObj.save(tcDataObj.java:478)
        at com.thortech.xl.ejb.beansimpl.tcProvisioningOperationsBean.retryTasks(tcProvisioningOperationsBean.java:4635)
        at Thor.API.Operations.tcProvisioningOperationsIntfEJB.retryTasksx(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvoca
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to store the string `BYUNJ` in a numeric field. Have you even tried to debug this?

Comment: As @NicoHaase mentionned you are trying to save a string into a number:
- tcAdapterTaskException: For input string: "BYUNJ"
- NumberFormatException: For input string: "BYUNJ"

Comment: Do accept the answer if it's correct

Answer (score 1):

I think I never tried to use EntityManager or UserManager with user login. Use usr_key instead.

Comment: @abama Please mark this answer as correct if it is.